# Authentic Windows 7 Theme in Windows 10?

Tags: wpf, windows, themes, windows-10

I develop a WPF desktop application that runs in a Citrix environment which applies the Windows 7 Basic Theme to my application. As a result, I run Windows 7 on my dev workstation to make sure the UI renders as intended.

I would like to upgrade it to Windows 10, however, but I have to find means of running my app with the Windows 7 theme within Windows 10. Incidentally (and oddly), if I run my app in *Windows XP compatibility mode* on Windows 10, it renders with the Windows 7 theme, so surely the OS is able to render the theme. I'm not sure I want to do all the testing of my app with *compatibility mode* activated, though...

I am also aware of 3rd party theming solutions, but to rule out any discrepancies, I would like to use the authentic Windows 7 theme from Microsoft.

Are there any tricks/tweaks/hacks out there to simply enable the Windows 7 theme for my app in Windows 10?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The WPF Theme for Aero is located in the `PresentationFramework.Aero` library, so add that as a reference. Then, in your `App.xaml` add the following merged dictionary to override the default theme.

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

I'm pleasantly surprised that they've finally updated WPF in .NET 4.5 to support Windows 8/10 themeing (they didn't at the start of Windows 8) with the following:

- `PresentationFramework.Aero2`
- `PresentationFramework.AeroLite`

Haven't seen it before today, need to work with .NET 4.5 more often ;)

Comment: That's a quite nice solution indeed. However, I have some legacy WinForms screens that I host through interop, which are unaffected by the WPF theme.

I really wish for a solution where Windows applies the Windows 7 theme to the entire process.

Comment: @TormodFjeldskår Unfortunately WPF controls are self-styled, always. Windows Forms as you know is entirely native. The only thing I could think of that would do everything is some form of Compatibility Settings, but that's not really practical.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the form an MDI with child windows as MDI Childs use the Windows 7 style as their border, or add some references to PresentationFramework.Aero/AeroLite/Aero2 and apply it in your code